# Adding properties in derived class

Tags: c#, design-patterns

So I am trying to code to an interface rather than an implementation. So I have a factory that returns an object that derives from Employee. So these objects may be something like Developer : Employee, Secretary : Employee, etc.

So I put all of the shared properties like FirstName, LastName, Email, etc. in the base class (Employee).

And I should put all of the properties specific to each type in just that type. So Developer would have some properties in it like Skills, ProgrammingLanguages, etc. but then I will not be able to access these properties from the Employee object unless I use the concrete type of Developer.

e.g.

```
Employee employee = new EmployeeFactory.CreateEmployee(EmployeeType.Developer);
employee.ProgrammingLanguages = "C#, Java, C++"; <-- compile error
```

What's the best way to go about this? Reflection...?

Comment: I think in this case you just need to case back up before the assignment.

Comment: In that case it doesn't make sense to code against the base class, since you're explicitly accessing a property from a derived class

Comment: If you resolve to go the reflection way you might want to use the dynamic keyword in .NET 4. That will make the code look cleaner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use generics and have something like

```
T EmployeeFactory.CreateEmployee<T>() 
{
     return new T();
}
```

And call it like

```
var dev = EmployeeFactory.CreateEmployee<Developer>();
```

That way you would end up with a typed Developer.

Comment: This would require that the type of `Employee` be known at compile time, which is not necessary with the current code.

Comment: True this code won't work if the type is variable, however the current code states the type more or less hardcoded (as an enum).

Comment: I like this. How can I send in a param to the constructor, though? public static T EmployeeFactory<T>() where T : Employee
        {
            string someParam = "";
            return new T(someParam);
        }

Comment: return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), new EmployeesRepository(connectionString));

Answer (score 4):

Why bother with a factory if you're going to be explicitly saying what type of employee to use?

Instead, you can just write:

```
Developer dev = new Developer();
dev.ProgrammingLanguages = "C#, Java, C++"; // compiles fine
```

Later, you can still add the "developer" to a list of employees, ie:

```
IList<Employee> theEmployees = GetEmployees();
theEmployees.Add(dev); // This is fine, since Developer is an Employee...
```

Comment: I see your point but I do like the factory because then I can pass in some initializations like the db connectionstring to each derived class and all of the logic for obtaining the initialization parameters will be in one spot. Although I suppose I can move that to the base class...Not sure really what the benefits/disadvantages would be of either.

Comment: @Joe: Yeah - it can easily be in the base class, and just passed through to the constructor.  There is really little advantage unless you're going to be "hiding" the real class.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, clearly when you try to do `employee.ProgrammingLanguages` you know that `employee` is of type `Developer`. So you can just cast to that:

```
Developer dev = new (Developer)EmployeeFactory.CreateEmployee(EmployeeType.Developer);
dev.ProgrammingLanguages = "C#, Java, C++";
```

Or more perhaps:

```
Developer dev = new Developer(); // If you don't really need the factory.
dev.ProgrammingLanguages = "C#, Java, C++";
```

In contexts where you don't know if this can be done or not, you can test with `is` or `as`.

Keep things at the level they make sense to deal with them at. Clearly it doesn't make sense to talk about the programming languages of someone who might not program, so its fine to work at the `Developer` level of the hierarchy. Code for dealing with holidays and salary should either be the same for all employees, or at least work through a common interface with the possibility of overrides, and so it would work at the `Employee` level of the hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me like, at least in this specific case, you shouldn't be using the base type.

You're working with something specific to a `Developer` rather than a generic `Employee` so you lose the benefit of working with the base type. In this case, just create a new developer:

```
Developer developer = new Developer();
developer.ProgrammingLanguages = "C#, Java, C++";
```

That being said, you could always try a cast back to the more specific type:

```
Employee employee = new EmployeeFactory.CreateEmployee(EmployeeType.Developer);

Developer developer = employee as Developer;
if(developer != null) developer.ProgrammingLanguages = "C#, Java, C++";
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case I would suggest using the simpliest solution. Create one method per one employee type, like this:

```
public Developer CreateDeveloper();
public Secretary CreateSecretary();
```

Why this "ugly" solution? Because you need to know the type in the client code either way. So why to complicate with generics/reflection? Simpicity is divine.